# SQL - Exclude rows from SELECT statement if a certain column combination exists in that row

Tags: sql

I have an SQL select statement with many columns. However I want to exclude an entire row if certain column combinations exist.

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE
WHERE NOT (COLUMN2 = 'A' AND COLUMN3 = 'B')
AND NOT (COLUMN2= 'B' AND COLUMN3 = 'C')
.
.
.
```

This doesn't seem to work, I am getting a "missing expression" error. What is the correct way to exclude entire rows when column combinations match certain conditions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a row can only match one of those conditions at one time, you should be using `OR`:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM YourTable
WHERE NOT (    
    ( COLUMN2 = 'A' AND COLUMN3 = 'B' )
     OR 
    ( COLUMN2= 'B' AND COLUMN3 = 'C' )
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c53ff31b0bdcd0c5984f69dc08ffa8c)*